# How to output which indexes ive found an element in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to loop through my array and find if it contains certain "searchWord", then I want to return which indexes this searchWord exists in. I also want to return how many times it's found.

This is how far I've gotten so far, made a loop to return "Yes" or "No" depending if it's found or not. But how do I return the actual indexes & times?

(Yes, I know there's some functions for this, but I want to *learn* how this is done.)

```
    Enter random words: <input type="text" name="words" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['words']) ? $_POST['words']: '' ?>" ><br/>
    Search Word: <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search']: '' ?>" ><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Print" />
    </form>
    <br>
    <?php
        $words = $_POST['words']; 
        $array = explode(" ", $words); // Split words into array
        print_r($array); // Print
        
        $searchWord = $_POST['search']; 
        
        
        foreach($array as $value)
        {
            if ($value == $searchWord)
            {
                echo "<br/>Yes";
                //break;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<br/>No";
                //break;
            }
        }

    ?>
```

I would like it to return something like "the word 'we' is found 2 times, on index 0 and 4"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness (without a loop), just search for the word and return the keys.  Then you can count them and display them:

```
$keys = array_keys($words, $searchWord);
echo "the word '$searchWord' is found " . count($keys) . " times, on index " . implode(' and ', $keys);
```

Comment: Nice one, second argument of `array_keys` is a very nice feature.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this to start:

```
$positions = [];
// iterate over array using both key (which is position) and value
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $searchWord) {
        $positions[] = $key;
    }
}
echo 'the word "we" is found ' . count($positions) . ' times, on index ' . implode(' and ', $positions);
```

The [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/kaMAO).

Answer (score 1):

In case you need all words.

There are some php-functions you may want to use:

### Code

```
$input = 'we like this stock we';

$wordsByIndex = str_word_count($input, 1);
$occurancesByWord = array_count_values($wordsByIndex);

foreach ($occurancesByWord as $word => $occurances) {
    echo sprintf(
        'The word "%s" is found %u times on index: %s' . PHP_EOL,
        $word,
        $occurances,
        implode(', ', array_keys($wordsByIndex, $word))
    );
}
```

### Output

```
The word "we" is found 2 times at positions: 0, 4
The word "like" is found 1 times at positions: 1
The word "this" is found 1 times at positions: 2
The word "stock" is found 1 times at positions: 3
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/JMNbD).

### References:

- [str_word_count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count)
- [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)
- [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just changed your code a bit, use an array to hold indexes, count of that array also gives you how many times it's found:

```
 <?php
        $words = "one two three one four one"; 
        $array = explode(" ", $words); // Split words into array
        print_r($array); // Print
        
        $searchWord = "one"; 
        
        $result = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($array as $value)
        {
            if ($value == $searchWord)
            {
                echo "Yes\n";
                $result[] = $i;
                //break;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "No\n";
                //break;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        print_r($result);
        echo count($result) . " times found\n";
?>
```

Result:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => one
    [4] => four
    [5] => one
)
Yes
No
No
Yes
No
Yes
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
)
3 times found
```